# Why electric force acceleration does not dominate thermal motion of electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Thermal velocity of electrons is in order of $10^{6}$ m/s. For electric field $E$ of magnitude 1 V/m, acceleration on electron would be in order of $10^{11}$ m/s^2. This acceleration should dominate thermal speed and drive all electrons in direction opposite to field with very great speeds. But drift speed of electrons is very low (for e.g. in order of $10^{-5}$ m/s in copper wire). Why is that?

Comment: What is the approximate time between electron collisions in a metal?

Answer (score 2):

> But drift speed of electrons is very low (for e.g. in order of
> $10^{-5}$ m/s in copper wire). Why is that?

Because collisions between the electrons and the positive metal ions, as the electrons attempt to move opposite the direction of the field, keeps the drift speed small. The typical time between those collisions is about 10$^{-14}$ seconds. On the other hand, those collisions do not effect the speeds of the electrons undergoing random thermal motion.

Hope this helps.